# getting a list of coordinates from a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 10 x 20 matrix of values (so 200 data points)

```
values = np.random.rand(10,20)
```

with a known regular spacing between coordinates so that the x and y coordinates are defined by

```
coord_x = np.arange(0,5,0.5)  --> gives [0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5...4.5]
coord_y = np.arange(0,5,0.25) --> gives [0.0,0.25,0.50,0.75...4.5]
```

I'd like to get an array representing each coordinates points so that
the shape of the array is (200,2), 200 being the total number of points and the extra dimension simply representing x and y such as

```
coord[0][0]=0.0, coord[0][1]=0.0
coord[1][0]=0.0, coord[1][1]=0.25
coord[2][0]=0.0, coord[2][1]=0.50
...
coord[19][0]=0.0, coord[19][1]=5.0
coord[20][0]=0.5, coord[20][1]=0.0
coord[21][0]=0.5, coord[21][1]=0.25
coord[22][0]=0.5, coord[22][1]=0.50
...
coord[199][0]=4.5, coord[199][1]=4.5
```

That would a fairly easy thing to do with a double for loop, but I wonder if there is more elegant solution using built-in numpy (or else) functions.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant `coord_y = np.arange(0,5,0.25)` in your question. You can do

```
from numpy import meshgrid,column_stack
x,y=meshgrid(coord_x,coord_y)
coord = column_stack((x.T.flatten(),y.T.flatten()))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [`meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) may be what you're looking for.

Here's an example, with smaller number of datapoints:

```
>>> from numpy import fliplr, dstack, meshgrid, linspace
>>> x, y, nx, ny = 4.5, 4.5, 3, 10
>>> Xs = linspace(0, x, nx)
>>> Ys = linspace(0, y, ny)
>>> fliplr(dstack(meshgrid(Xs, Ys)).reshape(nx * ny, 2))

array([[ 0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  2.25],
       [ 0.  ,  4.5 ],
       [ 0.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.5 ,  2.25],
       [ 0.5 ,  4.5 ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  2.25],
       [ 1.  ,  4.5 ],
       [ 1.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.5 ,  2.25],
       [ 1.5 ,  4.5 ],
       [ 2.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 2.  ,  2.25],
       [ 2.  ,  4.5 ],
       [ 2.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 2.5 ,  2.25],
       [ 2.5 ,  4.5 ],
       [ 3.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 3.  ,  2.25],
       [ 3.  ,  4.5 ],
       [ 3.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 3.5 ,  2.25],
       [ 3.5 ,  4.5 ],
       [ 4.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 4.  ,  2.25],
       [ 4.  ,  4.5 ],
       [ 4.5 ,  0.  ],
       [ 4.5 ,  2.25],
       [ 4.5 ,  4.5 ]])
```